# SUMPRODUCT two columns PYTHON

Tags: python

I am working on clipping loss coding.. I want an example code of how to SUMPRODUCT two columns

```
clipping = clipping_daily ['Column1'] * [int(x) for x in 'Column2'].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Do you just need to multiply each elements in `Column1` with the sum of `Column2`?

Comment: it looks like you are using numpy but using list comprehensions at the same time? what is the shape of your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you meant:

```
clipping = clipping_daily['Column1'] * clipping_daily['Column2'].astype(int)
```

Or you mean by?

```
clipping = clipping_daily['Column1'] * clipping_daily['Column2'].astype(int).sum()
```

Comment: you forgot the sum?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

With some inspiration from U12-Forward answer to make it all pandas-operations

This should do it (if I understand your problem correctly)

```py
sum_col_2 = clipping_daily['Column2'].astype(int).sum()
clipping = clipping_daily ['Column1'] * sum_col_2
```

or as one -liner

```py
clipping = clipping_daily ['Column1'] * clipping_daily['Column2'].astype(int).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you better use `groupby`:

```
clipping  = df.groupby(['Column1', 'Column2']).sum()
```